# How can you request DOM to not load images before Angular injects the correct variables?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this block of code:

```
<div class="image" ng-repeat="image in images">
    <img src="{{image.url}}"></img>
</div>
```

that is loading an image for each of the images I have in my controller. The image sources are set just fine, but while the DOM is loading, I get an error -

`Project/%7B%7Bimage.url%7D%7D net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`

This shows that before my angular code is manipulating the DOM, the DOM is already trying to load the image resource `{{image.url}}`. How can I prevent that from happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use [`ng-src`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc) directive as

```
<img ng-src="{{image.url}}"></img>
```

This directive will attach the image `src` attribute to the `img` tag only after expression inside `ng-src` is evaluated.

Comment: Is there a reference of properties such as src that also need a ng prefix? I am new to angular and went through a tutorial, but didn't notice this. It did fix the problem though!

Comment: um yeah you can refer the angular official documentation in here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/

Comment: :) oky glad to help you cheerz

Answer (score 1):

You can ng-cloak in your body tag.

```
<body ng-cloak>
<div ng-view></div>
</body>
```